# CSS/HTML: Make 2 children fill 50% of height of container div

Tags: html, css

This seems really simple, but I cant find any straightfoward way to carry this out.

Code: *(HTML)*

```
            <div class="col-6-12 subcontent-outer">
            <div class="subcontent">
                <h1>Header</h1>
                <p>
                   Stuff
            </div>
            <div class="subcontent">
                <h1>Header</h1>
                <p>
                   Stuff
            </div>
        </div>
```

So I need each `.subcontent` to fill 50% of the height of the `.subcontent-outer`, which works in modern browers, the height of the container div may change.

How can I do this?

Thankyou

Harley

Comment: Do you want the subcontents to be under each other? beside each other? full width?

Comment: Sorry, **under each other**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to close the paragraphs. Close them, like so:

```
       <div class="col-6-12 subcontent-outer">
            <div class="subcontent">
                <h1>Header</h1>
                <p>
                   Stuff
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="subcontent">
                <h1>Header</h1>
                <p>
                   Stuff
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

If that doesn't help yet, try this:

```
.subcontent-outer, .subcontent{
    float: left;
}

.subcontent{
    height: 50%;
}
```

**EDIT:**

Setting the height of a child element in percent of course requires the parent element to have a height specified.

In this case, you can easily test that with:

```
.subcontent-outer{
    height: 500px; /* for example */
}

.subcontent-outer, .subcontent{
    float: left;
}

.subcontent{
    height: 50%;
}
```

Comment: does .subcontent-outer have a height specified?

Comment: that might be the problem. try assigning a height to that.

Comment: Could I use min-height? The content may expand above (say) 300px.

Comment: Oh, no, it won't work, however I have a solution to the extra content. Overflow!